# Releasing new version of android app (Version)

Tags: android

I have an app on the android playstore. I want to release a new version of the app. I have checked my code, and the original appears without the app version line as follows `android:versionCode="1"`

Can I just add this line of code to the new release as below, even though it did not appear on the original?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="2"
    package="com..........." >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In build.gradle file of your app,

```
android {
        .
        .
        defaultConfig {
              applicationId "com......"
              minSdkVersion 15
              targetSdkVersion 22
              versionCode 2 //Should be greater than playstore
              versionName 1.1
        }
        .
        .
}
```

If the **versionCode** is not greater than the version code of the app present on playstore, it will ask you to update your app.

For checking the version code of your app on your device, install **Dexplorer** app and find the versionCode in manifest.xml

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you build your app with gradle (like expected) ignore the `AndroidManifest.xml` and adjust those kind of properties in the corresponding `build.gradle`-file, because gradle will overwrite those values in the manifest.

Also check for the field `versionName`

Comment: I don´t see `versionName` anywhere. Do you mean change the value on this line of code  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'`?

Comment: You are probably checking in the wrong `build.gradle`.  There is one in the root of your project, but also one in your module directory. You need the one with the `android {}` declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Eclipse, app version code is in the manifest.xml.

In Android studio, version code is stored in the file build.gradle in the app folder. If you want to change it, simply change in file or use menu "Project structure" (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S).

[image: Set version code in Android studio]

I don't believe you can publish app on play market without version code. I suggest you to check on developer console which version are published.

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle file should be like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nascenia.pfa"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1 // change here
        versionName "2.2" // change your version here
   }
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```